# How to copy file over to server using phpseclib (SSH2)

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I'd like to know how can I copy a file from localhost to the remote server using the **phpseclib** library? Which functions within the library would achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [example](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/examples.html#put). if you use the latest version of phpseclib you should use SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE const instead of NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE.

Comment: would it work using the `Net/SSH2.php` include or I'd have to include another too?

Comment: @Coder - you'd have to include `Net/SFTP.php`.